# Some need help on SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume the following table:

```
Select * 
from TestTable;

  Name      value
   B          3
   C          1
   A          2
```

I want to output as follows:

```
  Name      value
   A          1
   B          2
   C          3
```

Notice that in the result `Name`s are matched to their corresponding ordinal values from the `value` column.
Anyone help, how can I write the SQL statement?

Comment: `Select * from TestTable order by value` or `Select * from TestTable order by Name`

Comment: what is use mysql or sql server??

Comment: Is this your homework? :D

Comment: Your expected output is messed up. B has value 3, not 2.

Comment: @Kelvin - does your output needs to have columns decoupled and just show each row sorted separately ?

Comment: @KelvinSmith please clarify question as your sample is having columns decoupled ? is correct or just typo ?

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
    Name, Value
from 
    -- Order the Name table
    (select row_number() over (order by name) as id, Name from TestTable) as n
    inner join 
    -- Order the Value table
    (select row_number() over (order by value) as id, Value from TestTable) as v
    on n.id = v.id -- Combine two table by the ordered id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.Name, B.Value FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) as N, Name FROM Tab ) as A
INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Value) as N, Value FROM Tab) as B on B.N = A.N
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH 
 test1 AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Name)as id , Name  FROM Testing ),    
 test2 AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(order by value)as id , value  FROM Testing )  
SELECT Name,Value 
FROM   test1 
       JOIN test2 
          ON test1.id=test2.id
```

Comment: Two columns separately ordered and kept in a CTE and sorted from there .we get the required output

Comment: Please add the detail to your answer. :)

Comment: //comments added.please see above